# while scrolling a document fix a div if it's end appears on screen - using jquery

Tags: jquery

Suppose there is a div with height 1000px and body of document has a height of 2000px. I have a screen of 700px. Now when I scroll through the page, I would like to scroll both body and the div. but when the end of div appears on screen it should become fixed and should not scroll any more, but the window or body can scroll. When I scroll up again at exact 1000px the fixed positioning should be removed.

I am trying to make this thing happen since morning but unable to get any idea. Please have a look at my code:

```js
var fixmeTop = $('div').height();
var windowHeight = $(window).height();
var heightDiff = Math.abs(windowHeight - fixmeTop);


$(window).scroll(function() {

  var currentScroll = $(window).scrollTop() + windowHeight;

  if (currentScroll >= fixmeTop) {
    $('div').css({
      position: 'fixed',
      bottom: '0',
      top: 'auto'
    });
  } else {
    $('.site-content .widget-area').css({
      position: 'absolute',
      top: '0',
      bottom: 'auto'
    });
  }

});
```

```css
body {
  height: 2000px;
  background: #000;
}
div {
  height: 1000px;
  background: red;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div>

  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: *scrollmagic*  can do that - you can find it at http://scrollmagic.io/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few days ago i worked on a similar problem, i found [this](https://github.com/bigspotteddog/ScrollToFixed) jQuery Plugin on github. It works well, give it a try.